# Pycopula library inpu

Tags: python, pandas, github

I am having an issue with the `pycopula` library.

The example (provided on https://github.com/blent-ai/pycopula) imports a `csv` dataset and then uses it in the function. I have generated two random variable, uniformly distributed, and combined them into a `pd.DataFrame()` . I then tried to estimate a Clayton copula.

```
import pandas as pd 
from pycopula.copula import ArchimedeanCopula


x1 = np.random.uniform(size=3000)
x2 = np.random.uniform(size=3000)
X = pd.DataFrame(); X[0]=x1; X[1]=x2

archimedean = ArchimedeanCopula(family="clayton", dim=2)
archimedean.fit(X, method="cmle")
```

I am getting a `TypeError: '(0, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key`. If anyone has used this library before and knows what input does the function take, I would be grateful. The full documentation link that it is provided on GitHub redirects me to a non-existing website (Error 404). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method `fit()` takes data in numpy array type. You can't put a dataframe into it.

> X : numpy array (of size n * copula dimension)

Use `Dataframe.to_numpy()` to change into right type. Hope it works.